# How to set up kitchen printer in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I just installed Odoo version 9 locally. I haven't found the way to configure an order printer to be used with the Point of Sale module. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you have any solution for this problem. I have same issue with odoo 12 pos. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up kitchen printer using **pos_restaurant** module. After installing this from app list you can see one menu in **POS >> Configuration >> Order Printes** in this menu you can setup printer

Comment: Can i configure kitchen printer with out poxbox? Actually i only have printer, need to  print both receipt and kitchen order on same printer.

Comment: Yes you can configure it without POSBOX.

Comment: I configured order printer as follow,  Name, Proxy ip address '0.0.0.0, localhost, 192.168.50.24' etc. but not printing.

Comment: Both printers IP different and configuration of this is different. For order printer you can configure through **pos.config** but for kitchen printer you need to install **pos_restaurant** module.

Comment: I installed pos_restaurant module, i entered order printer details in many2many field, then i can see a button 'Order' in pos interface. Nothing printing

Comment: Does any console log is there in browser ?

Comment: I getting this log error on
`Blocked loading mixed active content “http://192.168.50.38:8069/hw_proxy/print_xml_receipt?session_id=5c409d266fb897452095c66f856b699804b647da”`

Comment: Try to run it in chrome browser.